# ArrayOutOfBoundException runtime error

Tags: java, arrays, exception, stack

I am trying to run this code, to learn java, but I encountered a runtime error:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayStack<E> implements StackInterface<E>{
    private E[] theStack;
    private int capacity;
    public static final int CAPACITY = 1000;
    private int top = -1;

    public ArrayStack() {
        top = -1;       // empty stack
        theStack = (E[])(new Object[10]);  // make room for at least 10 items
    }

    public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    /*The constructor creates a new stack with the specified capacity, and throws an IllegalArgumentException
     if the specified capacity is less than zero.*/
        if (initialCapacity < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                  ("initialCapacity must be >= 1");
        theStack = (E[]) new Object [capacity];
        capacity = initialCapacity;
        top = -1;

    }

    public void push(E element) throws NullPointerException,IllegalStateException {
        if (size() == capacity)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is full.");
        if (element == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Can't push a null element");
        }

        if (theStack.length == top + 1) {
            theStack = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(theStack, theStack.length * 2);
        } // else, there already is room for one new element
        top++;
        theStack[top] = element;
    }
    public int size() { return top+1; }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top < 0);
    }
    public E pop() throws EmptyStackException{
        E element;
        if(isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        element = theStack[top];
        theStack[--top] = null;
        return element;
    }

    public int depth() {
        return size();
    }

    public int capacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void flip() {
        reverse(theStack, 0, size() -1);
    }

    public void reverse(E[] x, int i, int j){
        if(i<j){
            E tmp = x[i];
            x[i] = x[j];
            x[j] = tmp;
            reverse(x, ++i, --j);
        }
    }

    public void transferTop(ArrayStack<E> s) throws EmptyStackException {
    /*The transferTop method transfers the element from the top of stack s to the top of the current stack (this).*/
        if(isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        E x;
        x = s.pop();
        this.push(x);

    }

    public E replaceTop(E element) throws NullPointerException {
    /*The replaceTop method replaces the top element of the stack with the specified element and returns the original top element.*/
        if(element == null) throw new NullPointerException("Can't push a null element");
        theStack[top] = element;
        return theStack[top];
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s;
        s = "[";
        if (size() > 0)
            s += theStack[0];
        if (size() > 1)
            for (int i = 1; i <= size() - 1; i++) {
                s += ", " + theStack[i];
            }
        return s + "]";
    }

    public void status(String op, Object element) {
        System.out.print("------> " + op); // print this operation
        System.out.println(", returns " + element); // what was returned
        System.out.print("result: size = " + size() + ", isEmpty = "
                + isEmpty());
        System.out.println(", stack: " + this); // contents of the stack
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o;
        //ArrayStack(int initialCapacity)
        StackInterface<Integer> A = new ArrayStack<Integer>(100);
        A.status("new ArrayStack<Integer> A", null);

        A.push(7);
        A.status("A.push(7)", null);
        o = A.pop();
        A.status("A.pop()", o);
        A.push(9);
        A.status("A.push(9)", null);
        o = A.pop();
        A.status("A.pop()", o);
        ArrayStack<String> B = new ArrayStack<String>();
        B.status("new ArrayStack<String> B", null);
        B.push("Bob");
        B.status("B.push(\"Bob\")", null);
        B.push("Alice");
        B.status("B.push(\"Alice\")", null);
        o = B.pop();
        B.status("B.pop()", o);
        B.push("Eve");
        B.status("B.push(\"Eve\")", null);
    }
}
```

The A.push(7) operation generated the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I was wondering what needs to be changed in my push() method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: `------> new ArrayStack<Integer> A, returns null`
`result: size = 0, isEmpty = true, stack: []`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`
` at ArrayStack.push(ArrayStack.java:61)`
` at ArrayStack.main(ArrayStack.java:172)`
``
``

Line 61: is "theStack[top] = element;" line
Line 172: is "A.push(7);" line

Comment: `------> new ArrayStack<Integer> A, returns null`

`result: size = 0, isEmpty = true, stack: []`

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

` at ArrayStack.push(ArrayStack.java:61)`

` at ArrayStack.main(ArrayStack.java:172)`

``
``

Line 61: is "theStack[top] = element;" line
Line 172: is "A.push(7);" line

Comment: ------> new ArrayStack<Integer> A, returns null
 result: size = 0, isEmpty = true, stack: []
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  at ArrayStack.push(ArrayStack.java:61)
  at ArrayStack.main(ArrayStack.java:172)



Line 61: is "theStack[top] = element;" line
Line 172: is "A.push(7);" line

Comment: @ThomasStets , asked to post this stacktrace on the post not here

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant portions of the stack trace there, where you can format it properly and where people can see it. Never add question details (especially code) to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
theStack = (E[]) new Object [capacity];
capacity = initialCapacity;
```

You allocate a zero-sized array because you use `capacity` when it's set to deafult 0 and not the correct value.

Comment: that was it. I changed the order of the code and it worked! Thanks